# What is the highest scoring single kill possible without situational bonuses?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

I'm not talking about with some of the situational bonuses (e.g., **First Blood**, **Revenge**, **Chain**, etc.) but a pure, single kill as if you were in the training ground.

The highest scoring kill I've been able to get was a hidden, focused, incognito poisoning which nets **1000 points** (with the default score bonus for poison):

- 300 points - hidden
- 150 points - focused
- 350 points - incognito
- 200 points - poison

**Is there anything I can practically do to get higher than that?***

<sub>* besides crafting the poison to have an additional 100 point bonus</sub>

It's not possible to get an acrobatic kill (200 points) from a hidden spot AFAIK.  It's not possible to get an aerial kill (100 points) focused and hidden AFAIK.  Grab kills (450 points) are just not very common and you can't get enough of the other bonuses with it.

Comment: I'd be perfectly fine with an answer that can adequately explain that this is as high as it gets.  I'm just thinking there's some bonus that I'm not aware of that can be earned here.  I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying out all different kinds of kills, I believe this is as best as it gets.  A lot of the other kill bonuses are not attainable or as rewarding as these kills.

With the different kill bonus types, these bonuses are mutually exclusive:

50 - Reckless
100 - Discreet
250 - Silent
**350 - Incognito**

100 - Kill
100 - Aerial Kill
200 - Acrobatic Kill
**300 - Hidden Kill**
450 - Grab Kill  (To get this, you have to give up the **Poison** bonus and you only get an additional 150 points)

**150 - Focus**

**200 - Poison**

You *must* use the hidden gun for these so you give up a lot of the above bonuses:

100 - Mid-Air
100 - Execution

These are situational and doesn't really yield any of the above bonuses:

50 - Grounded
100 - Contested Kill
50 - Ground Finish

All other bonuses in the game depend on the situation and game type so are not the kind of bonuses you have complete control over and not what I'm interested in.

Answer (score -1):

I found a kill worth 5900 points (!!!)

Here are the bonuses in it:

```
Recovery +50
Hidden Kill +300
Incognito +350
Focus +150
Revenge +50
Poison +300
Chain +50
Greater Variety +400
Extreme Variety +600
Assist Kill +50
Diversion +50
Multi-kill +100
Streak Bonus +550
Score x2
```

Comment: Not sure this fits the question either, since Jeff's asking for the highest base kill without most of the bonuses in this video.

Comment: I'm referring to only a single kill with no other extra bonuses that depends on what you did earlier.  So **Chain** is excluded because you have to had stunned someone before the kill.  Same with the variety bonuses, revenge, team/game mode bonuses, etc. etc.  I'm sure it's possible to fabricate a situation to maximize a single kill score with all those bonuses as shown in the video but that's not what I'm looking for.  Yes, that's exactly it @Anna.

Comment: The video _is_ impressive however but it is answering a different question unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

I found a kill worth 6700 points (it was staged, but it's still cool).
The actual score shows up at 2:50